# How do I add a link to a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

How do I add a link to

```
<Col key = {item.id}>
     <StoreItem {...item}/>
</Col>
```

so that it takes me to

```
<Route path = '/' element = {<Home />} />
```

Here is the source code.

```
import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {StoreItem} from '../components/StoreItem'
import storeItems from '../data/items.json'


export function Store(){
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Store</h1>
            <Row xs={1} md={2} lg={3} className = 'g-3'>
                {storeItems.map(item => (
                    <Col key = {item.id}>
                        <StoreItem {...item}/>
                    </Col>    
                ))}
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Home} from './pages/Home'
import {Store} from './pages/Store'
import {About} from './pages/About'
import {Navbar} from './components/Navbar'

function App() {
  return( 
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Container className = 'mb-4'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = '/' element = {<Home />} />
          <Route path = 'Store' element = {<Store />} />
          <Route path = '/about' element = {<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom`, this is achieved using the `Link` component. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="/">to home</Link>
```